# Is it possible to create a new row of tabs in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I'd like a new row of tabs just below the existing row. Is this possible in xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with the standard `UITabBar`.  You would have to build your own solution with UIViews.  I agree with Keller, its a bad design idea - I think it would use up too much screen space.  Perhaps have a Table View with all the tabs as rows and drill down into your views instead?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's possible but sounds like a really bad design choice. I would either use a "More..." tab in your tab bar or a UISegmentedControl.